# How do I get each individual tab to have its own set of sub tabs?

Tags: html, css

I would like MTH025-ENG111 to only be visible once I mouse hover over it, if you have any more tips or tools to help me it will be appreciated.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title> follow the cult </title>
   </head>
   <body> 
   </body>
   <h1 style="text-align:center"> CULT </h1>
   <br></br>
   <hr>
   </hr>
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <input type="button": value="men" 
      button onclick= 
      <ul style="list-style-type:dark circle">
         <li> MTH 025 </li>
         <li> JPN 101 </li>
         <li> CSE 102 </li>
         <li> CEC 101 </li>
         <li> ENG 111 </li>
      </ul>
      <input type="button": value="women">
      <input type="button": value= "new arrivals">
      <input type="button": value="popular" >
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share more details about exactly what you want? A visual can also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the opacity of the li elements to 0 then when hover over it make it 1

try it:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title> follow the cult </title>

    <style>
        .ul li {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .ul li:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
</body>
<h1 style="text-align:center"> CULT </h1>
<br></br>
<hr>
</hr>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" : value="men">
    <ul class="ul" style="list-style-type:dark circle">
        <li> MTH 025 </li>
        <li> JPN 101 </li>
        <li> CSE 102 </li>
        <li> CEC 101 </li>
        <li> ENG 111 </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" : value="women">
    <input type="button" : value="new arrivals">
    <input type="button" : value="popular">

</div>
```